# Static array, variable size allowed?

Tags: c++

I have a function like this

```
void foo( int i)
{
   ...
   uint8_t buf[ i];
   ...
}
```

and I don't understand why the compiler is not complaining...
I'm using

```
g++ -c -g -Wall
```

to compile

Any ideas??

Comment: It's a compiler extension. I'm sure you can find a duplicate on here.

Comment: [Variable Length Array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array)

Comment: I think you'll get a warning if you specify e.g. `-std=c++11` and have a `-pedantic` option.

Comment: why would the compiler be complaining, give a reason why ?

Comment: @StephaneRolland: One might expect it to complain since this isn't valid C++.

Comment: @MikeSeymour oh sorry, it's been so long I no longer use array I didn't notice the dynamic i in buf... thanx for reminding me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a [GCC compiler extension](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html). It is allowed by the standard for a conforming implementation because it does not break any well-formed code (as long as it issues a diagnostic). It is, of course, not portable and therefore not recommended.

With the `-pedantic` option, you'll get the following warning:

```
warning: ISO C++ forbids variable length array ‘buf’ [-Wvla]
```

Comment: It's allowed **if** the compiler issues a diagnostic.

Comment: oh! Is that new or something? I mean the extension

Comment: @santi It's been there for a good while now.